# JavaScript Image container without src error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm validating my website and I have small gallery and when people click on picture there it opens in container. I have used javaScript for this but w3 validator gives error on my container because it has no src. My question is there any way to remove this error ?

```
<img src="img/1203138907710_o.jpg" alt="one" onclick="myFunction(this);">


<div class="container">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <img src="" alt="a" id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
</div>         

function myFunction(imgs) {
    var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
    var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
    expandImg.src = imgs.src;
    expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

Also extra question I have 32 errors and 600 warning from bootstrap.min.css what do you think I should do ?

Comment: Where is `#imgtext` in your HTML?

Comment: I got you edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

You can place a hash ( # ) to avoid the src error. It is not recommended for `href` attributes because it may cause side-effects, but for a `src` attribute of an image it is sufficient.

```
<img src="#" ...>
```

### Alternative:

You may also use a data URI as a placeholder. The smallest `png` image, as far as I'm aware, is a 1x1 square. (*the actual encoding is in the code snippet below*)

```
<img src= "data:image/png;base64, ...encoding" ...>
```

### Code Example

```html
<img src="img/1203138907710_o.jpg" alt="one" onclick="myFunction(this);">


<div class="container">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <img src="#" alt="a" id="expandedImg" style="width:50%">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="a" id="expandedImg2" style="width:50%">
</div>
```

---

### Proof of Passing:

[image: Image of Passing W3 Validation]

Comment: the # helped perfectly , thank you very much. What do you think about the other problem with bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @JavaBegginerIdiot not really. As a professional developer for many years I don't know anyone who even validates through w3c. It seems superfluous, but if you must, you should keep in mind that it's minified which probably doesn't lend itself to validation. Secondly, if you're insistent, you'll simply have to go through error by error, and warning by warning, and correct them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The easiest approach is to use a placeholder image in the `src`. You can also remove the `<img>` and create it dynamically inside the container.

```html
<img src="img/1203138907710_o.jpg" alt="one" onclick="myFunction(this);">

<div class="container" id="expandedImgContainer">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(imgs) {
    var div = document.getElementById("expandedImgContainer");
    var expandImg = div.querySelector('img') || document.createElement("img");
    expandImg.alt = "a";
    expandImg.style.width = "100%";
    expandImg.src = imgs.src;
    div.appendChild(expandImg);
    div.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```